# Creating a beta version of site on subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have a website that I have been working on for a while. All this time I have been editing the live website files on the web server for my development. I finally realized that it was stupid to edit the live site. My "quick" solution is to copy everything from example.com to beta.example.com. I will edit the beta subdomain and when I have a feature to release, I will copy and replace the existing code on the example.com site. Great.

That would be great if I could get it to work. I'm having troubles with my .htaccess files for both domains and URL rewriting.

For my example.com site, I use a .htaccess like so: (there are only a handful of pages on my site)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/recent
RewriteRule ^ recent.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/about
RewriteRule ^ about.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/category/(.*)/(.*)
RewriteRule ^ category.php?id=%1&name=%2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/category/(.*)
RewriteRule ^ category.php?id=%1 [NC,L]
```

The problem with the beta.example.com site is that it always redirects to just regular example.com. It removes the beta subdomain.

**What is the proper .htaccess code to get subdomain sites separate from non-subdomains?**

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure settings for beta.example.com on your server. Setting like DNS in the domain account and if you are using windows(IIS)/linux(Apache) server then configure it same way as you have configured example.com.
If you are using shared hosting then you must have CPanel for your website. then create new directory through that and point the beta.exapmle.com to that directory.